# How to call the value of a numericInput to use it in a function in a SidebarPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

I will create a matrix in a `sidebarpanel` using the `shinyMatrix` package. To determine the dimension (number of rows or columns) I will use a `numericInput` widget. How can I call the `numericInput` value as the value of `m` in the `matrix` argument?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  
  sidebarPanel(
       numericInput("nbr","Dimension", value=2,step=1,min=0,max=100),
       matrixInput(
        inputId = "matrix",
        label = "Input Correlation Matrix",
        value = diag(m+1),                 ## I want to call the value of numericInput intead of m.
        class = "numeric",
        cols = list(names = F,editableNames = T),
        rows = list(extend = F,names = F,editableNames = T)
      )
      
   )
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the element to the server to be able to do what you want. I used `shinyWidgets::autonumericInput` to better suit your case:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

ui <- shinyUI(
  
  fluidPage(
    
    sidebarPanel(
    
    shinyWidgets::autonumericInput(
      inputId = "nbr",
      label = "Dimension", 
      value = 2, 
      step = 1, 
      align = "center",
      minimumValue = 0,
      maximumValue = 100,
      decimalPlaces = 0,
      style = "box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px orange"
    ),
    
    uiOutput(outputId = "serversidematrix")
    
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$serversidematrix <- renderUI({
      
      matrixInput(
        inputId = "matrix",
        label = "Input Correlation Matrix",
        value = diag(input$nbr + 1),
        class = "numeric",
        cols = list(names = F,editableNames = T),
        rows = list(extend = F,names = F,editableNames = T)
      )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am very grateful :) neves, I didn't know the "shinyWidgets" package. Thank you so much.